# Local HTML editor like Windows Live Writer

Tags: c#, html, html-editor

I'm looking for some *open source* editor that allow to write locally HTML to be posted later on a remote site via some protocol. This in order to create a light CMS that is driven all client side. Does something like this already exists ?

Comment: There are lots of potential solutions depending on your exact needs.
First, by "open source" do you mean free or do you mean you need to edit the code?  Second, are you looking for a complete solution or just a control that will do html editing? (in other words should it have the ability to open the files, make edits, and save changes to a remote site or will you write an app that does everything but make changes?  Third, if a control, is it to be embedded in a winforms or web application?

Comment: Why is this tagged C#? It's not clear if you're wanting a control you can drop into a C# application, or if you're looking for a stand-alone program that can do this.

Comment: Open source is the preferred one. I will write the app so something very versatile is required.

Comment: @Cold Dray, I'm looking for a C# OS project if one exists. This is the Tag reason

Comment: @Darin, Windows ( WPF is ok )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at [HtmlTextBox](http://winformhtmltextbox.codeplex.com/) for WinForms or [RichText Editor](http://michaelsync.net/2009/06/09/bindable-wpf-richtext-editor-with-xamlhtml-convertor) for WPF.